# Get just the URL from background-image property

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get just the URL from the background-image property:

Right now I do this:

```
(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-image")).replace('url(','').replace(')','');
```

But if in the background-image there are other things like webgradient and so, I will get them too. How can I avoid that?

Comment: this should find all the urls in the rule: getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundImage.match(/url\([^)+]\)/gi)

Comment: This is not working...For this: ```"url(http://css.bbystatic.com/images/_headerFooter/icons-new-e42e71d385bbad8d5ccba0cfeb3983a1.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 242, 0) 0%, rgb(247, 207, 0) 100%)""``` it returns ["url("] -

Comment: oops: /url\\([^\\)]+\\)/gi

Comment: dandavis, that is catching the whole URL, with the url( and ) I want the URL itself though. Can you add an answer please?

Comment: add    .split(/[()'"]+/)[1] to the end to grab the url itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing this:

```
var m = (window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-image")).match(/url\(([^)]+)\)/i); 

if (m) { ... m[1] ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

here a a way to do it without accounting for multiple background-images using only core JS:

```
var bg="url(http://css.bbystatic.com/images/_headerFooter/icons-new-e42e71d385bbad8d5c‌​cba0cfeb3983a1.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 242, 0) 0%, rgb(247, 207, 0) 100%)";

var imgUrl=(
        bg.match( /url\([^\)]+\)/gi ) || 
        [""]
    )[0]
    .split(/[()'"]+/)[1];

alert(imgUrl);
```

imgUrl will be either a url or undefined, depending upon what you feed it. 
it should be 100% crossbrowser/node.js ok, no dom involved...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this might be the regexp you need

```
/url(\s*\S*\s*)/i
```

If the regexp dandavis listed works you can do this

```
.match(/url([^)+])/gi).replace('url(','').replace(')','')
```

Comment: The match() method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object. your replace cannot be applied to array.

Comment: does .match(/url([^)+])/gi)[0].replace('url(','').replace(')','') work?

Answer (score 0):

Log to console all `background-image` URLs, without parentheses and quotes:

```
var element = document.getElementById('divId');
var prop = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('background-image');
var re = /url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi;
var matches;
while ((matches = re.exec(prop)) !== null) {
    console.log(matches[2]);
}
```