# How do you find the background-image of a DIV without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

How do I find the background-image attribute of a DIV without the use of jQuery and only using Javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Get background-image URL of <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/javascript-get-background-image-url-of-div) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825927/get-just-the-url-from-background-image-property

Comment: This is a very, *very* basic question which has featured in lots of already-answered questions. Please [search the site](http://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking questions in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("element").style.backgroundImage;
```